# I can create a library in angular, but that depends on another native library of NPM

Tags: angular, npm

Case of use:

Dependencias:
I want to create a library for angular 6, this library consists of a service with logic to analyze string (for example SQL syntax)

Questions:

1. I want to know, if at the moment of creating my library in angular, I can make use of [chevrotain] (https://github.com/SAP/chevrotain) inside my library
2. If the number 2 is correct, what problems can I face in the future?
3. In case of not hitting number 1 and 2, what alternatives do I have to be able to use [chevrotain] (https://github.com/SAP/chevrotain) in my new library?

I appreciate any kind of answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you can, by add a dependency in your libraries package.json to chevrotain. When someone installs your library, it will automatically install chevrotain.

Initially you may have thought to use peerDependencies, but in this case it should be a dependency as your package won't run without it. See also [this post](https://blog.angularindepth.com/npm-peer-dependencies-f843f3ac4e7f) that explains it in a bit more detail.